# Generic functionality of map function in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, generics

I'm learning Spark with basic knowledge of java.

In my first Spark program, I saw code that looks like this:

```
JavaRDD<String> tweetsRDD = spContext.textFile("/home/andrea/Documents/SparkTest");
for (String s : tweetsRDD.take(5)) {
    System.out.println(s);
}           
System.out.println("Total tweets in file : " + tweetsRDD.count());
JavaRDD<String> ucRDD = tweetsRDD.map(str -> str.toUpperCase());

// Print upper case lines
for (String s : ucRDD.take(5)) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I don't understand what  `str -> str.toUpperCase()` means in the map function.

After Googling, I found out that map is an function declared in the interface `JavaRDDLike<T, This extends JavaRDDLike<T, This>>`.

The function signature is: `map(Function<T, R> f)`

May I know please how `Function<T, R>` and `str -> str.toUpperCase()` relate to each other as a parameter in map function ?

I'm not able to understand this functionality `str -> str.toUpperCase()`! How that looks like `Function<T, R>`?

My second question is about the JavaRDDLike interface. I saw one of its argument types say `This extends JavaRDDLike<T,This>`? What does this mean? Is it pointing to a class implementing this interface ?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(str -> str.toUpperCase())` is called a **Lambda Expression**.

They are anonymous methods (methods without names) used to implement a method defined by a functional interface. A Function Interface has one an only one Abstract Method.

Lambda provides the capability of performing pipeline operation on the data and also gives you the power of multi core processing.

The operator `->` is called the arrow operator. It divides the lambda expression into two parts.

The left side specifies the parameters required by the expression, which could also be empty if no parameters are required.

```
n -> n*n
```

The right side is the lambda body which specifies the actions of the lambda expression. It might be helpful to think about this operator as “becomes”. For example, “n becomes n*n”, or “n becomes n squared”.

Read more from the documentation

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html